# Django admin reverse foregin key relationship

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a number of different models connected to the User model through a foregin key relationship. I would now like to display all the attributes from the objects connected to the User model in the main admin overview.

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    address = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user_firstname', 'user_lastname', 'address')

    def user_firstname(self, instance):
        return instance.user_id.username

    def user_lastname(self, instance):
        return instance.user_id.lastname

admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

The code above works perfectly well to display attributes from "User" in "Userprofile", but how do I do this the other way around? In my code I currently have 4 different objects connected to the User object so keen to find a way to display all the data there.

Answer (score 1):

use inlines

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

admin.py

```
class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        BookInline,
    ]
```

more info read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly to display everything within the individual objects, but is it possible to display all the attributes together with the list_display items the overview?